# HowTo configure Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) with Joomla as server?

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, angularjs, cors

I am writing a web app that is embedded within a website running on [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org). On the client-side, I'm using AngularJS. Angular's `$resource` object follows the patters for Cross Origin Resource Sharing -- i.e. it makes an `OPTIONS` request before making any `GET` request.

In Joomla, I have a `task` in one of my controllers that receives the client's request, performs some authentication logic in Joomla, and then responds with data. If I make a simple `GET` request, this responds appropriately. However, I can't figure out how to make Joomla give the appropriate "OK" response when it receives an `OPTIONS` request.

**Is there a Joomla-specific way to make this happen?** If not, how can one respond to `OPTIONS` using plain PHP? My searches are drawing a blank.

(If it makes any difference, this will eventually be a same-origin request. It's only cross-origin in our development process. However, I believe that Angular will make the `OPTIONS` request regardless.)

Comment: why do you care about options? I use $resource and I don't feel it exists.

Comment: I can work around it, but I'm trying to be proper and stick to the specs.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how to make CORS work:

Lets say you're on this page origin.com/test.php and your JavaScript on this page makes a request to target.com.

To initiate a cross-origin request, a browser sends the request with an Origin HTTP header. The value of this header is the domain ( origin.com ) that served the page. So in this case it would be:

Origin: http://origin.com

If target.com supports CORS, then it needs to reply with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header in the response. The value of the header indicates what origin sites are allowed.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://origin.com

To allow access from all domains, target.com needs to send the HTTP header:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

For more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Best an simplest explanation of CORS I have found on the net :)